# How to read p,d and q of auto.arima()?

Tags: r, arima

How can I get `p,d and q` values in `ARIMA(p,d,q)` model estimated by `auto.arima(mytimeseries)`?

> arima_model <- auto.arima(mytimeseries,ic='bic')

If we look at the output of

> arima_model$arma

we get,

> [1] 1 0 0 0 1 2 0

What is the meaning of the numbers appear in above sequence?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
arimaorder(fit)
```

Comment: So what did the numbers in his output mean?

Comment: Read the `arima` help file: "A compact form of the specification, as a vector giving the number of AR, MA, seasonal AR and seasonal MA coefficients, plus the period and the number of non-seasonal and seasonal differences."

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the help file of `auto.arima` and navigate to the section "Value", you are directed to the help file of `arima` function and there you find the following (under the section "Value") regarding the `arma` slot:

> A compact form of the specification, as a vector giving the number of AR, MA, seasonal AR and seasonal MA coefficients, plus the period and the number of non-seasonal and seasonal differences.

That is what the seven elements you reported correspond to. In your case, you have a non-seasonal ARIMA(1,2,0).

Answer (score 1):

In case, it might be easier to understand for some people:

```
non_seasonal_ar_order = model_fit$arma[1]
non_seasonal_ma_order = model_fit$arma[2]

seasonal_ar_order = model_fit$arma[3]
seasonal_ma_order = model_fit$arma[4]

period_of_data = model_fit$arma[5] # 1 for is non-seasonal data

non_seasonal_diff_order = model_fit$arma[6]
seasonal_diff_order =  model_fit$arma[7]
```